# Can't access the COM interface

Tags: com, queryinterface

I am working with the scantest of application documentation (shocker), and what there is seems to be misleading/contradicting. I will ask the software company as well, but their last reply took weeks. In the meantime....(thanks).....

I am trying to access the [alledged] COM interface of a GUI application we'll call: Xyz

My Question: Would the results below imply to you that there IS no COM interface available, that it needs to be registered, etc...

### USER MANUAL STATES:

Here are the only two quotes related to the app's COM Interface ability:

1. "Since Xyz is a 32 bit application using COM (Component Object Model) components,
   running Xyz from a network......".
2. "You can access the Xyz.Interface COM object to query for information and present it in a format you like".

### CODE EXAMPLE 1:

Dim xyz_com
Set xyz_com= CreateObject("Xyz.Interface")
xyz_com.Visible=false

### RESULT 1:

"Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Visible'"

### CODE EXAMPLE 2:

Dim xyz_com
Set xyz_com= CreateObject("Xyz.Interface")

### RESULT 2:

The initial application screen appears which - if I AM starting the application in 'server mode' as they say - I wouldn't think I would have the screen showing.

### CODE EXAMPLE 3:

Dim xyz_com
Set xyz_com= CreateObject("Xyz.Interface")
xyz_com.QueryInterface()

### RESULT 3:

"Object doesn't support this property or method: 'QueryInterface'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the results below imply to you
>   that there IS no COM interface
>   available, that it needs to be
>   registered, etc..
>   The CreateObject call succeeds, so the COM interface exists and is registered.

Some comments:

- You can't directly call QueryInterface like that from VB
- You need to cast the object to the correct interface before setting the Visible property. Try `Dim xyz_com as Xyz.Interface` instead of just `Dim xyz_com`

Comment: Sorry - didn't mention this is VBScript/WSH where the AS doesn't go over to well. But thanks for the info that the interface exists and is registered. I am further than I was ;)

Comment: OK a little further. Using VS I looked for the COM interfaces and found their methods. They don't appear to have the one I need (shocker), but even more troublesome. When I use CreateObject() for say, an Excel application, I have the option of setting visible=false so that the VB code can use Excel without seeing the screens. THESE COM interfaces seem to have no such ability: I CreateObject (Xyz.Interface) and BANG I have a full-fledged GUI being created, screens and all. Does that seem to defeat the purpose of the COM interface? I could have started the GUI normally and gotten the screens....